# Excel 2016. I need a way to see if 2 columns match or not

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I've got a shipping list that I want to edit. If whats in column A don't match column B it turns red. Is there any way to do this? That away when i print out the list and its missing something on there its highlighted red and easy to spot.

Comment: Are they a one to one match, as in A1 = B1 or do you need to search column B for every cell in Column A as in A1 is any where in column B?

Comment: You are probably looking for a simple VBA script, but as Scott pointed out, the matching parameters need to be better defined. An example data set would help.

Comment: @RHughes VBA would probably be overkill when a simple countif does the job nicely.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Countif() formula to count if the value in column A also exists in column B. The formula can be in the worksheet or in a conditional formatting formula.

In the following screenshot, the formula in C2 and copied down is

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B:B,A2),"packed","not packed")
```

Or highlight the unpacked items in column A with the conditional formatting using the formula

```
=AND(LEN(A2)>0,NOT(COUNTIF(B:B,A2)))
```

The NOT() is required to turn the 0 counts in to triggers for the conditional format and the LEN() ensures that the format is applied only to rows with values in column A.

[image]